# ¿Por qué no puedo ejecutar la instrucción webdriver.Chrome()?

Tags: python, macos, selenium

Tengo problemas, al intentar ejecutar:

```
>> from selenium import webdriver

>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

Y el error se obtiene al ejecutar:

```
>> driver = webdriver.Chrome()
```

El error que obtengo es el siguiente:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File       "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 69, in __init__
desired_capabilities=desired_capabilities)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 92, in __init__
self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 179, in start_session
response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, capabilities)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 236, in execute
self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 192, in check_response
raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: session not created exception
from unknown error: bad inspector message: {"method":"Page.loadEventFired","params":{"timestamp":6424,763637}}
  (Session info: chrome=54.0.2840.71)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.24.417412     (ac882d3ce7c0d99292439bf3405780058fcca0a6),platform=Mac OS X 10.12.1 x86_64)
```

¿Por qué antes me funcionaba (hace 1 mes) y ahora ya no? He intentado actualizar tanto los binarios de Chrome como Selenium, ambos están actualizados y continúo con el mismo error.

Comment: No he conseguido hacer que Chrome funcionara, así que he probado suerte con Firefox y ha funcionado, solo he tenido que añadir en $PATH la dirección dónde tengo almacenado geeckodriver. Pensé en hacer el mismo procedimiento para Chrome, pero ni situando chromedrive en ~/bin (aquí es donde almaceno geeckodriver) ha funcionado.

Answer (score 1):

Debes colocar la ruta de `chromedriver` como parámetro, en mi caso:

```
chromedriver = '/usr/bin/chromedriver'
chrome = webdriver.Chrome(chromedriver)
```

Answer (score 0):

A nivel de webdriver, Chrome y Firefox funcionan de manera bastante diferente.

Parece que la versión 54 de Chrome ha traído problemas de compatibilidad con su chromedriver. Ahora ya está disponible la versión 2.25 pero tampoco solucionará el problema.

Un workaround que puedes probar es cambiar el locale. Probablemente lo tengas en español, cosa que puedes comprobar poniendo en el terminal:

```
$ locale
```

...y te devolverá:
LANG="es_ES.UTF-8"

Cambia el locale a en_US, con el comando:

```
$ LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

...y prueba a lanzar de nuevo el driver. Si te funciona, añade la instrucción a tu profile y esperemos a una nueva versión corregida de Chromedriver :)